# Could someone take a crack at this number theory problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is stated as follows:

If $\mathrm{gcd}(a,m)=1$ and $X$ is a complete residue system $\bmod m$, then the set obtained by multiplying each member of $X$ by $a$ is also a complete residue system.

I am not too sure how to start this question, and I know I'm overthinking it. I think using the modular cancellation law would be of use, but I'm not sure exactly.

Could someone give me a hint? I want to get this.

**EDIT:**

I should add that I got it to the point that, if every element of $X$ and $Y$ (the other set) are multiplied together, we see:

$X:(m-1)!$

$Y:a^{m-1}\cdot(m-1)!$

I'm not sure if that's the right route.

Comment: Assume to the contrary that $a.X$ is not a complete residue system. What does that tell you about $a.X \pmod{m}$ ?, by $a.X$ I mean the set with every element of $X$ multiplied with $a$.

Comment: I've never heard the term "complete residue system modulo $m$", that's a very convoluted way of saying "the set $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$"... So you want to show that multiplication by $a$ permutes that set, in other words, that it's a bijection.

Comment: Then there exists a y in Y such that y is not congruent to some x in X mod m... Do you mind elaborating on how I would go that route?

Jack M: how would one go about showing that this is a bijection? This course is throwing so many new topics at me, It's very hard keeping on top of everything.

Comment: @Lerbib In other words $Y$ has a repeated element (since, both X and Y are supposed to have $m-1$ terms excluding the $0$ element). I.e., there is a pair of elements $x_1,x_2 \in X$ such that $ax_1 \equiv ax_2 \pmod{m}$.

Comment: Awesome, that's perfect.  Makes complete sense now. EXCEPT, how can be sure that it is a repeated element? Since it can never be greater than m, taking each number mod m?

Comment: @JackM A *complete residue system* is a complete system of reps for all congruence classes in a residue ring, e.g. $\,\Bbb C\,$ is a complete residue system for $\,\Bbb R[\,i\,]/(i^2\!+1).\ $

Comment: @Lerbib $Y\setminus \{0\} (\subseteq X\setminus \{0\})$ is supposed to have $m-1$ elements and when we claim it's not a complete residue system $\pmod{m}$ that means some pair of elements in $Y$ leave the same residue $\pmod{m}$. Not sure what's confusing here.

Comment: @sciona
Thanks. I'm new to this stuff. But your answer helped.

Comment: @JackM the difference is that the one is a set of integers, while the other is a set of sets of integers (the residue classes). For example $\{0,1\}$ is complete residue system modulo $2$ yet so is $\{5,20\}$.

Comment: Let the elements of $X$ be $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m$. Since this is a complete residue system, if $1\le i\lt j\le m$, then $x_i\not\equiv x_j$ modulo $m$.  We need to show that all the $ax_i$ are incongruent modulo $m$. Suppose to the contrary that there exist $1\le i\lt j\le m$ such that $ax_i\equiv ax_j\pmod{m}$. Then since $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime, we have $x_i\equiv x_j\pmod{m}$, which is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to X$ that, to each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ associates the unique element $x\in X$ such that $n\equiv x\pmod{m}$.

Now consider the map $g\colon X\to\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $x\mapsto ax$.

I claim that the map $f\circ g\colon X\to X$ is injective.

Indeed, if $f(g(x))=f(g(y))$, we have $g(x)\equiv g(y)\pmod{m}$, so
$$
ax\equiv ay\pmod{m}
$$
Since $a$ is coprime with $m$, we can cancel it out and, from $x\equiv y\pmod{m}$, with $x,y\in X$, we conclude $x=y$.

Therefore the map $f\circ g$ is also surjective and…

Comment: What a thorough answer. Thank you for taking the time to do this.

I'm only second year college right now, trying to learn as much as I can before I go hard in mathematics. These type of answers are really helpful.